# How do I share files between Windows and Ubuntu in a Wubi setup?

Tags: partitioning, wubi

I am running Ubuntu Wubi in Windows 7 on my netbook.

I want to share files between the two OS's.

I know how to make a partition in Windows and give it a name like `D:` but how do I then access it from Ubuntu?

Comment: Does Wubi in 7 count as dual boot?

Comment: @d3vid: I think not, I've changed the title.

Answer (score 3):

> The Windows partition where you installed Wubi is available as `/host` within Ubuntu (`Places > Computer > File System > Host`).
>
> All the other partitions will be available under `Places > Removable Media`

Here's the [source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_access_the_Windows_drives.3F).